# How to achieve a centered header over right-aligned columns of numbers when the header is long relative to the width of the column of numbers

Tags: tables, header-footer, alignment, makecell

I have difficulties to produce a relatively wided centered header entry over a relatively narrow column of right-aligned numbers. The other way around it works fine with the *makecell* package as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

Short headers are nicely centered over wide columns with right-aligned numbers:

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{crr}\toprule
Case    &   \thead{A}   &   \thead{B}\\ \midrule
1       &   80401               &   45054564\\
2       &   55454555454         &   424545\\
3       &   505                 &   175\\
4       &   65                  &   16\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}


However, long headers \emph{appear to be right-aligned} over narrow columns with right-aligned numbers:

\vspace{10mm}


\begin{tabular}{crr}\toprule
Case    &   \thead{AAAAAAAA}    &   \thead{BBBBBBBBB}\\ \midrule
1       &   80                  &   4\\
2       &   5                   &   45\\
3       &   505                 &   175\\
4       &   65                  &   1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result looks as follows:
[image]
However, as seen in the lower part of the screenshot, the headers AAAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBB appear to be right-aligned even though technically speaking it is centered as in the case above with the short header entries over the long number entries.

I would be grateful to learn how make the headers of the second table look centered. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1]S[table-format=3]S[table-format=3]}\toprule
{Case}    &   {\thead{AAAAAAAA}}    &   {\thead{BBBBBBBBB}}\\ \midrule
1       &   80                  &   4\\
2       &   5                   &   45\\
3       &   505                 &   175\\
4       &   65                  &   1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]